# mathjax render while server watch

Tags: hugo

When I run 'hugo server --watch', I can visit the site by localhost:1313
But this is a http connection and is marked unsecured in chrome (or firefox), hence the equation is not rendered, they remain latex codes. When upload to server, e.g. github.io, it is rendered.

Is there a way to make mathjax render equation in server --watch mode? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of making `hugo server` use https at present. I assume you are using a CDN to load MathJax - instead you could [install it locally](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#installing-your-own-copy-of-mathjax) in your Hugo site's `static` folder ([Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/themes/customizing/#replace-static-files)) and edit your Hugo theme to point to your local copy of the script.

Local installation has the advantages that you will be able to run MathJax locally over http, and that your your site will be more secure. (If you use a CDN without a `hash` attribute in the script tag, or with a browser that doesn't support `hash` attributes, then the CDN can change the JavaScript that runs on your site.) However, local installation has the disadvantage that people will have to download MathJax from your site instead of from the (probably much faster) CDN.

If you want to put the time and effort into it, then you could use a tool like Gulp or Grunt to set up a build process where you use a local version of MathJax on your local machine, and the CDN version on your production servers. But this will be overkill for most people.